# Android button textAppearance

Tags: android, button, styles, appearance

I can change button text appearance by setting it right within object like this:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/login_btn_bypass"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#878787"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

but not when using textAppearance within style

```
// in layout xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_btn_login"
    android:textAppearance="@style/login_button_text_appearance" />

// in style definition 
<style name="login_button_text_appearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#a7a7a7</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

anyone knows why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you should use :

```
style = "@style/login_button_text_appearance"
```

instead of:

```
android:textAppearance="@style/login_button_text_appearance"
```

The `android:textAppearance` is just an attribute like any other attribute ( `android:textSize`, `android:textStyle`, etc..) , and the value of the style is not acceptable as a value for that attribute.

**EDIT :**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_btn_login"
    style="@style/login_button_text_appearance" />
```

Comment: I don't see any android:style on Button, how should I apply your suggestion?

Comment: there is no attribut named android:style , it name directly style , see my edit

Answer (score 15):

The values of attributes defined using `textAppearance` are applied before the values of attributes in a style. A `Button` is a `TextView` with a style applied, and the default style of a Button will override your textAppearance (Android 2.3 for example will set it to `?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse`) and `textColor`.

`textAppearance` accepts styles as values; `android:textAppearance="@style/login_button_text_appearance"` is the normally correct way to set a `textAppearance`, but not for a `Button`:

If you're changing the text colour of a `Button`, you should also enforce a custom background image because if you don't, one device will use a dark background image (motorola defy) and another will use a light image (htc desire) which may make the text difficult to read.