# android:textAppearance for Arabic

Tags: android, textview, arabic

The default font in a TexView renders Arabic horribly.

Is there a way I can set TextView to a style that will render Arabic nicely, perhaps using `android:textAppearance`?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813

Comment: I think these links will help you....[link 1][1]


[link 2][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337680/using-androidtextappearance-on-textview-edittext-fails-but-style-works
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245259/android-button-textappearance


Thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a typeface and set it to all components that display text  (TextView, EditText, Button, ...). To do this:

1- Copy your font file into your assets folder

2- In your Activity:

```
someTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/someFont.ttf");
```

3- Everywhere you have a View object:

```
someTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_text_view);
someTextView.setTypeface(someTypeFace);
```